# Applying the Usa visa from a country where I don’t have resident permission

Tags: visas, usa

I  am from Turkey.  I live in Nigeria and residency. It is difficult to get Nonimmigrant visa from Nigeria. I have valid visas for The UK and Schengen ara and I will be visiting  the UM and , France  and Germany. Can I apply for the USA visa from these countries  since I don’t have residency. My reason is to apply from another country is I got refused once when i wanted to travel with my students after then I travelled another country again this year I travelled to the UK . My students want to visit to the USa but my company is not willing to allow me coz last time all got visa but me that is why it damaged school’s reputation .that is why , first i have to get visa then i can organize my students

Comment: Your chances will not be improved by applying from another country, although your positive travel history since last application may help.

Comment: @Giorgio I'm not sure this is a dupe. This question is about a citizen of country A who is resident in country B but wants to travel to country C to apply for a US visa there; the other question is about a citizen of country A who is resident in B wants to apply for a US visa in B.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I struggled with this one, trying to figure what might help OP and not be discouraging (and OP hasn't returned since posting).

Comment: @Giorgio Fair point that the question is nearly a month old.

Comment: @DavidRicherby where I am, it's been two months :)

Comment: @Giorgio That's because you're in a different timezone. One of the ones where people can do arithmetic. ;-)